Crafting a wand with abilities that modify a spell
When a wand is created, what abilities, feats, or special effects can affect the resulting spell?
If a phoenix sorcerer crafts a wand, can they apply their bloodline effect, turning the wand into one of healing?
What if they have Blood Havoc? Do their spells from wands they make have the +1? Or if they are elemental bloodline, can the wands they make match the elements?
I some specific feats can apply, because metamagic works, as stated here in the rules.

Magic Items and Metamagic Spells: With the right item creation feat, you can store a metamagic version of a spell in a scroll, potion, or wand. Level limits for potions and wands apply to the spell’s higher spell level (after the application of the metamagic feat). A character doesn’t need the metamagic feat to activate an item storing a metamagic version of a spell.

What determines if an effect is or is not allowed to modify a spell that is put into a wand?

related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156284/can-a-cleric-spontaneously-convert-a-wand-into-a-cure-inflict-spell

related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114799

The question is a little all over the place as it was asking three kind of related questions, one of which was answered via an edit which provided the source.
The answer to both "can phoenix sorcerers apply their ability" and "can blood havoc be applied" is no. There are no general rules stating that class abilities can be added to magic item effects.
When crafting wands you are able to apply a known metamagic feat because the metamagic rules specifically state that, just as it was stated under Metamagic Feats that you can't apply them after it's been crafted and you are trying to cast.

The modifications made by these feats only apply to spells cast directly by the feat user. A spellcaster can’t use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a wand, scroll, or other device.

Well not needed, here are some sources I looked at when coming to an answer.

Wands and bonuses to caster level and/or damage?
Who is the caster for wands?


So if I understand your reasoning correctly... The absence of wands stating the spell stored in them could be modified, means that abilities that the caster could use to modify/manifest the spell, cannot be applied when storing that spell into a wand? They can still choose what caster level they can have the wand be upon creation though... If they have buffs to their caster level (Such as an ioun stone) this could still affect the CL they choose to make the wand at? Or is metamagic the ONLY thing that applies?

@Erudaki As you both have to have the caster level and have to pay for the caster level of the spell in the wand, thats fairly balancing for wands. Being able to have additional effects on it like +1 healing from the casting would make those wands more valuable than wands without, but that extra ability isnt accounted for in the pricing. I expect the rules were created to be uniform, fair, and reasonably short. It also makes random generation of loot easier.

That response confuses me. It seems to contradict one of the related posts you added, where magical lineage was deemed something that could affect the final product of the created wand. Benefiting from a metamagic feat, at a reduced level. This seems to imply that certain traits (ones pertaining to metamagic) can affect the product, and CL bonuses can... Which is what led me to asking the final question in my post. So far... CL bonuses: Implicit Yes. | Metamagic: Explicit yes. | Modifications to Metamagic : Implicit Yes | Everything else : Implicit No |
Would that be a correct assessment?

@Erudaki When a creator triggers a spell to create a magic item (search here for act of working), the creator isn't casting a spell, so any effect that says when you cast a spell (like the phoenix bloodline or blood havoc mutation) can't be put into a wand, potion, or scroll. Magical Lineage is odd because it changes the spell level at which a spell is prepared then that spell is triggered from that slot at that spell level, a lot like a metamagic effect. (I still don't think ML should apply, but I can see why others do.)
